# how to add a background image to a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

I am trying to add a background image to my UITextView, but there doesn't seem to be an option to do so.  I have tried adding an imageView with the image as a sub view

```
self.bioTextView.delegate = self
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: self.bioTextView.frame)
imgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "text_field_bio")
self.bioTextView.addSubview(imgView)
```

But this didn't work either. The color of the textView Background is clear.  I have also tried including sending that imgView to the back, but that didn't work either.

Comment: put an image view behind the text View and make the textview clear background

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add the foll0wing two lines and check once

```
bioTextView.addSubview(imgView)
bioTextView.sendSubview(toBack: imgView)
```

or use

```
bioTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Image.png"))
```

**updated**

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(20), width: CGFloat(400), height: CGFloat(400 )))
    textView.text = "this is a test \n this is test \n this is a test"
    let img = UIImageView(frame: textView.bounds)
    img.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.addSubview( img)
    self.view.addSubview(textView)
    textView.sendSubview(toBack: img)
```

**you get the output**

[image]

Comment: I am using that second option and it's working, but is there a way to clip the UIImage to the frame of the TextView, or set the images resizing mode so that it resizes itself to the frame of the textView?

Comment: @GabeSpound - chioce is yours

Comment: @GabeSpound - set the images resizing mode so that it resizes itself to the frame of the textView - it automatically adjust the frame based on superviee,